# What does "select 1 from" do?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I read some articles but really didn't understand what does `select 1 from` do?  Someone says "you should use `select 1` instead of `select *`".  Here is an example table:

```
cust_id     cust_name       cust_address

1000000001  Village Toys    Mapl
1000000002  Kids Place      South
1000000003  Fun4All         Sunny
1000000004  Fun4All         Riverside
1000000005  The Toy Store   53rd
```

What will the result be when I write `select 1 from customer_table` what does this statement do?

Comment: About a *decade* or so ago, it was reasonable advise to suggest `select 1` instead of `select *` in e.g. an `EXISTS` clause. The optimizer was improved a long time ago. It was *never* a replacement for "get all columns from this result set".

Comment: Did you try it???

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
select 1 from table
```

will return a column of 1's for every row in the table. You could use it with a where statement to check whether you have an entry for a given key, as in:

```
if exists(select 1 from table where some_column = 'some_value')
```

What your friend was probably saying is instead of making bulk selects with select * from table, you should specify the columns that you need precisely, for two reasons:

1) performance & you might retrieve more data than you actually need.

2) the query's user may rely on the order of columns. If your table gets updated, the client will receive columns in a different order than expected.

Answer (score 42):

The construction is usually used in "existence" checks

```
if exists(select 1 from customer_table where customer = 'xxx')
```

or

```
if exists(select * from customer_table where customer = 'xxx')
```

Both constructions are equivalent. In the past people said the select * was better because the query governor would then use the best indexed column. This has been proven not true.

Comment: Can you provide some details about "This has been proven not true"?

Comment: Some people have done extensive performance tests to determine the difference, but you can do it yourself easy enough.

See this gist as example: https://gist.github.com/FilipDeVos/3f9f0ab9396e2761b7420e7573d584c2

Answer (score 31):

It does what you ask, `SELECT 1 FROM table` will `SELECT` (return) a `1` for every row in that table, if there were 3 rows in the table you would get

```
1
1
1
```

Take a look at [Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1) which may be the issue you were described.

Comment: Why would I want that?

Comment: @Imray This is useful when you are just interested whether the condition in your `WHERE` clause is true or false. It is often used in sub queries.

Answer (score 9):

The statement `SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable` just returns a column containing the value `1` for each row in your table.  If you add another column in, e.g. `SELECT 1, cust_name FROM SomeTable` then it makes it a little clearer:

```
            cust_name
----------- ---------------
1           Village Toys
1           Kids Place
1           Fun4All
1           Fun4All
1           The Toy Store
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) in EXISTS/NOT EXISTS
```

`EXISTS(SELECT CCOUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITIONS)` - the `EXISTS` condition will always return true irrespective of CONDITIONS are met or not.

`NOT EXISTS(SELECT CCOUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITIONS)` - the `NOT EXISTS` condition will always return false irrespective of `CONDITIONS` are met or not.

```
SELECT COUNT 1 in EXISTS/NOT EXISTS
```

`EXISTS(SELECT CCOUNT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITIONS)` - the `EXISTS` condition will return true if `CONDITIONS` are met. Else false.

`NOT EXISTS(SELECT CCOUNT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITIONS)` - the `NOT EXISTS` condition will return false if `CONDITIONS` are met. Else true.