# Trigger not triggering

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've got two tables as per diagram below

[image]

here is sql script for `USERS` TABLES

```
USE [NewUser]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[USERS]    Script Date: 15/12/2014 18:26:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERS](
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SureName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [USID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_USERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [USID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And for `ADDRESSES` TABLE

```
USE [NewUser]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ADDRESSES]    Script Date: 15/12/2014 18:26:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES](
    [AID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PostCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ADDRESSES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ADDRESSES_USERS]
FOREIGN     KEY([USID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USERS] ([USID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ADDRESSES_USERS]
GO
```

After that I have created a `TRIGGER` using

```
USE [NewUser]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[autoupdate]    Script Date: 15/12/2014 18:33:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[autoupdate]
    ON [dbo].[USERS]
    AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TEMPID INT
    SET @TEMPID = (SELECT USID FROM INSERTED)
    UPDATE ADDRESSES
    SET USID = @TEMPID
END
```

The purpose of the `TRIGGER` is to insert UID automatically on the second table as soon as a new row is added or updated in first table.

But its not doing what I was expecting it to do.

Screenshots

USERS TABLE

[image]

ADDRESSES TABLE

[image]

`USID` from table `USERS` and `AID` from table `ADDRESSES` both has "Is Identity Set to YESS"

Comment: the aim was to update `USID` on second table (ADDRESSES) automatically as I insert row into first table (USERS).
But second table is unaffected. Nothing happens!

Comment: Your trigger has a major flaw. It assumes there will only every single row operations. If you use this code it not only can't handle multiple row operations it will update the ENTIRE Addresses table every single time.

Comment: rene It doesnt... let me add the screen shots.
@SeanLange I dont mind as long as it works

Comment: @rene check the screenshots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is SQL Server, not MySql - please remove the conflicting RDBMS tag.

With triggers, you'll need to handle set data - the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudocolumns are tables, not single rows.

Also, assuming that you aren't going to be updating the PK `[USID]` on Users, you won't need to handle an UPDATE in the trigger, just INSERT and DELETE, and it looks like you've already decided to handle deletes on user with `ON DELETE SET NULL`, which will set the USID foreign key to NULL in Addresses.

So this leaves INSERT - I'm guessing here you only want to insert an empty address for new users?:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[autoupdate]
    ON [dbo].[USERS]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO ADDRESSES(USID)
        SELECT USID FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES a WHERE a.USID = i.USID)
        AND i.USID IS NOT NULL;

END
```

Comment: can you explain your code a bit more please? I did not understand this block...

        SELECT USID FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES a WHERE a.USID       = i.USID)
           AND i.USID IS NOT NULL;

Comment: We basically just want to check that the user id from the newly inserted address row doesn't already exist in the addresses table. This is probably more relevant to an UPDATE trigger in this case. If you don't want this behaviour, you can revert to just inserting directly into addresses?

Comment: I meant What is `SELECT 1` AND `i` here?

Comment: `i` is just an alias for the INSERTED pseudotable, and `SELECT 1` is commonly used with `EXISTS` - it doesn't really matter what you put after the select when [checking for existence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039938/what-does-select-1-from-do)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your trigger to do anything the way you've designed it, you need to have records already in the Addresses table. Once a record exists, it's USID will be updated when a record is updated or inserted in the Users table.