# SQL query on self joins

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

Given a table, world with 3 cols: country, continent, population how do i get an output that shows the countries for each continent with the largest population?

Here is my code:

```
select tb1.country, tb1.population from world tb1 join world tb2
ON tb1.continent=tb2.continent
Where tb1.population>tb2.population;
```

my output only returns me 1 country from 1  continent.

Comment: The question is awkward,what do you mean `countries for each continent with the largest population`?Largest population of a continent?First x countries per continent in population?

Comment: using MAX() and GROUP BY maybe ? some sample table data would be helpful here if you could provide that.

Comment: Top country from each continent, or each country for continent with the highest population?

Comment: There are lots of ways to skin this cat. The solutions documented in the manual also work well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this approach before and it seems to work well

```
SELECT a.country, a.population
FROM world a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM world b
    WHERE b.continent = a.continent
    AND b.population > a.population
)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/979c14/2)</kbd>

<sub>Be patient, SQL Fiddle seems really slow today</sub>

---

To elaborate, the sub-query acts as a filter for the outer query, eliminating any rows (via `NOT EXISTS`) per continent where a country with a greater population exists.

This also returns countries with equal maximum populations. If you need only one country per continent, you would need some further elimination data.

Comment: what does the 1 mean?

Comment: It's just *"any value"*. The sub-query acts as a filter. We're not interested in any data from it, just whether or not it has any results. You could use `SELECT *` but many years ago, that was less performant. Old habits die hard

Comment: @Jenn more info here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039938/what-does-select-1-from-do

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be the following:

```
select w1.country, w1.population from world w1,
(select max(w2.population) as p from world w2 group by w2.continental) T
where w1.population = T.p
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Also just fyi, you can select all your code and hit the `{}` button to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL does not have analytic functions you can fake it with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
  Continent,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(Country ORDER BY Population DESC), '|'), '|', 1) AS Country,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(Population ORDER BY Population DESC), ','), ',', 1) AS Population
FROM Populations
GROUP BY Continent;
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
SELECT
  p.Continent,
  p.Country,
  p.Population
FROM Populations p
     INNER JOIN
     (
       SELECT Continent,
              MAX( Population ) AS max_pop
       FROM Populations
       GROUP BY Continent
     ) m
     ON (   p.continent  = m.continent
        AND p.population = m.max_pop )
GROUP BY Continent;
```

Or:

```
SELECT
  p.Continent,
  p.Country,
  p.Population
FROM Populations p
WHERE p.population =
       (
         SELECT MAX( Population )
         FROM   Populations m
         WHERE  p.continent = m.continent
       );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94931e/8)