# How to check in an insert into command in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: Student, Books and Borrows:

- **Student** (id, name, FK_borrow)
- **Books** (id, name, nbre_books_available int)
- **Borrows** (borrow_from, borrow_to, FK_student, FK_books)

I want to insert values into the table `Borrows` after checking if the column `nbre_books_available` is not 0, and update it.

This my attempt

```
private void fillborrow()
{
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into borrows Values ('"+dateTimePicker1.Value+"','"+dateTimePicker2.Value+"',"+int.Parse(textBox1.Text)+","+int.Parse(textBox2.Text)+")" ;

    cn.Open();
    int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    if (a == 0)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur"); 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ajouter avec success"); 
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "update books set nbre_current = nbre_current - 1 where CodeO = " + int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

I don't know how to Add the requete that check if the nbre_books_available column is 0 or not

Comment: Do Not concat+values+into+strings+like+that+to+make+SQL.  It is error prone and makes gruesome code.  Use SQL parameters always.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you for your comment i haven't used SQL parameters yet i'm still learning from some tutorials and most of them use the concatenation,and yes doesn't look that good,i will surely get into parameters

Comment: @tedman you **must** get into parameters; it doesn't need to be hard - tools like "Dapper" make it incredibly easy; without parameters: your system is toast within minutes on the internet

Answer (score -1):

This is essentially the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489254/check-duplicate-entry-before-inserting-into-sql-server/48489414?noredirect=1#comment83974992_48489414)

You can perform your `exist` check at the same time as inserting and then check the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

If it returns 0 then no rows were inserted, otherwise it was successful.